# How to close window/app when i cant see it? ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x-windows

Im running ubuntu. I just tried to play supertux but my LCD didnt support the resolution and all i got was a blank screen and music playing. I tried to close it and go back to the desktop by pressing ctrl + z but that didnt work so i had to hard reset my computer!

In future what should i press when this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctrl+alt+backspace will kill your X session and restart is, dumping you at the login window.

Comment: any idea where i find the supertux config files so i can change screen res?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue! Have you tried looking at the man page and seeing if there are any hints?

Comment: started it with -w worked ok :)

Comment: recent versions of ubuntu (Karmic for sure, i think Jaunty too) have been nixing this option in the default configuration.  google for `DontZap`, or check these instructions for Jaunty: http://maketecheasier.com/restore-ctrl-alt-backspace-in-ubuntu-jaunty/2009/05/17

Comment: Hm, that's pretty unnecessary. I haven't had an X session open on Ubuntu in forever, so I didn't know that. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a Virtual Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F4), log in with your password and type "killall programname", after typing the first few letters of the program name, press tab and it should autocomplete. (e.g. killall supertux) When done Ctrl+Alt+F7 returns you to your desktop.